# Accessing ansible host_vars with variable name

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to get the host_vars using a variable and getting warning messages, is there any better way to achieve this?

My Inventory yaml is

```
dev_cluster:
  hosts:
    host-vm01:
      install:
        httpd: true
        zookeeper: true
        mysqld: true
    host-vm02:
      install:
        httpd: true
        zookeeper: true
        mysql: true
    host-vm03:
      install:
        httpd: true
        mysql: false
```

This is my When block, the `component_name` is the extra variable that will be changing while calling the play.

```
- name: ADD HOST
  add_host:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    group: component_name_group
    delegate_to: localhost
    changed_when: false
  when: 
    - hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.{{ component_name }} is defined
    - hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.{{ component_name }}
```

Below is the warning message I am getting.

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.{{ component_name }} is defined
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.{{ component_name }}
```

I tried various possibilities and ran out of options now.

```
The conditional check 'hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.[component_name] is defined'
The conditional check 'hostvars[inventory_hostname].install.'component_name' is defined'
```

If I put single quotes or double quotes erroring out. Please help

Thanks

Comment: `when: hostvars[inventory_hostname].install[component_name] is defined`

Comment: `when: install[component_name] | default(false) | bool`

Answer (score 1):

Create the group *component_name_group* in the first play and use it in the second play.

For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: "Create group component_name_group"
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    host_install: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                           zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                               map('extract', hostvars, 'install'))) }}"
    hosts_component: "{{ host_install|dict2items|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: "[?value.{{ component_name|d('none') }}].key"
  tasks:
    - block:
        - assert:
            that: hosts_component|length > 0
            fail_msg: Nothing to install.
        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: component_name_group
          loop: "{{ hosts_component }}"
      run_once: true

- name: "Install {{ component_name }}"
  hosts: component_name_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Install {{ component_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

creates the dictionary *host_install*

```yaml
  host_install:
    host-vm01:
      httpd: true
      mysqld: true
      zookeeper: true
    host-vm02:
      httpd: true
      mysql: true
      zookeeper: true
    host-vm03:
      httpd: true
      mysql: false
```

and, for example, given *component_name=httpd*, creates the list of the hosts and adds them to the group

```yaml
  hosts_component:
    - host-vm01
    - host-vm02
    - host-vm03
```

The second play then installs the utility

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e component_name=httpd
PLAY [Create group component_name_group] *****************************
  ...
PLAY [Install httpd] *************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [host-vm01] => 
  msg: Install httpd on host-vm01
ok: [host-vm02] => 
  msg: Install httpd on host-vm02
ok: [host-vm03] => 
  msg: Install httpd on host-vm03
  ...
```